# Which one to buy? Rx470 or Rx580?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I will start with fifteen mining rigs next week (each 6 GPUs). I have two options one is RX470 and other one is RX580 which one should i go with?

Answer (score 1):

*I can see that you asked this question 8 months ago, therefore I'm writing this for the benefit of others and also invite you to add your own experiences.*

I am using 6 x XFX RX470 (4G) and 1 x XFX RX580 (8G) on Ubuntu 16.04.03 using Claymore and get better hash rates and reliability from the 470 range after bios modding.

Out of the box, the XFX RX580 worked at 27MH/s whilst the RX470 range worked at 21 or 24MH/s.  Things got interesting with the RX470 range after flashing the bios, giving 28MH/s for each card, stable at a pull of under 100W each.

I don't have any luck getting the RX580 over 27MH/s that was stable, however I have read that other users have had good results overclocking using Windows.

Value changes had to be painstakingly tested and adjusted for each card, hence my reluctance to share on this forum, but the time spent adjusting the cards was well worth it (due to having dual bios cards)

From my own experience, using compute drivers on Ubuntu 16.04.03, I would go for the RX470 if you can get hold of them.